# Javascript Package (CircleType Not Defined)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use this package

https://github.com/peterhry/circletype

I have the following code

```
<script src="circle/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
<script>
  new CircleType(document.getElementById('demo1'))
  .radius(384);
</script>
```

However, I keep getting ReferenceError:CircleType not defined.Any idea what I might be doing wrong? In the console it also says SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on circletype.min.js. could something be wrong with the file?

Comment: The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: Yes it is. It is a local file and it was found 9ms.

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on circletype.min.js. That appears in the console could something be wrong with the file?

Comment: sounds like yes there's an error in that file which means it can't use it

Answer (score 2):

1. Is the library on your server/file system? If not, download it from https://github.com/peterhry/CircleType/releases and unzip it to where you want to load it from.
2. Is it loaded before you try to use it? ie:

   ```
   <script src="circle/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     new CircleType(document.getElementById('demo1'))
     .radius(384);
   </script>
   ```

and not:

```
    <script>
      new CircleType(document.getElementById('demo1'))
      .radius(384);
    </script>
    <script src="circle/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
```

3. Does your browser support the library (or the other way around)? Try loading it in latest latest version of chrome. If that works, transpile it to support more browsers using [babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [google closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).
4. Try separate your code out. ie:

   ```
   <script src="circle/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     const circleType = new CircleType(document.getElementById('demo1'));
     circleType.radius(384);
   </script>
   ```

In this case, the issue was that the code was not supported by the OP's browser. This was solved by updating Babel's targets [from 'last 2 versions' to ' 99.9%'](https://github.com/JoelEllis/CircleType/commit/80bc3013ea4c37f552010f9a977bd758bd2b6ee4).

Comment: All those have been done. I just checked the console and there was this.. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on circletype.min.js. Could something be wrong with the file?

Comment: @James Very likely yes, though it is *possible* its a valid file but uses JS features your browser doesn't support.

Comment: try load the unminified version, see if that makes a difference. if that works, use a different minifier for yourself, and file a issue on their issue tracker. there is a chance, as you said, that it's something 
 wrong with the file, or your browser doesn't support it.

Comment: there is a fair chance your browser doesn't support it, as in their .babelrc file they have this code:`"targets": {
        "browsers": "last 2 versions"
      }`, effectively meaning that it's only using code supported by newer browsers. it'll be using const or var.

Comment: I've built a custom version that should work on any browser at https://github.com/derpmarine168/CircleType/releases/tag/2.3.0  ;)

Comment: Holy crap thank you.